# InlineUIElement not respecting clipping area of TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, clipping, inlineuicontainer

I have a TextBlock that contains some text in some `Run` elements, and which is set to `CharacterEllipsis` textclipping mode. However I also have a few `InlineUIElements` that contains some custom buttons.

The problem is the buttons are showing up outside of the bounds of the TextBlock when they should be "clipped".

Am I missing some explicit setting somewhere to make these elements respect the bounds of the parent? Oddly, the text is clipped just fine, and shows the character ellipsis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [ClipToBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx) to True on the TextBlock.  It will still behave a little bit weird, though: all of the InlineUIContainers will be aligned with the start of the ellipsis, so you will get a little bit of every one of them on the edge of the TextBlock.

Comment: That works much better, thanks. :) Not noticing any obviously weird behavior right away.